# RabbitMQ HelloWorld messages being blocked on localhost?

Tags: java, message, rabbitmq, mq

I have been running the hello world RabbitMQ example with the code below:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello World!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());

        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close(); 
      }
    }
```

and:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;

public class Recv {
      private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

      public static void main(String[] argv)
          throws java.io.IOException,
                 java.lang.InterruptedException {

          ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
          factory.setHost("localhost");
          Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
          Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

          channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
          System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

          QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
          channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

          while (true) {
              QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
              String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
              System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
         }
    }
}
```

When I run the receiver it listens to the queue, and the sender says its sending the message but doesn't seem to close. I then run:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

The queue is definitely being created.

However when I run:

```
rabbitmqctl list_connections
```

I get the following output

```
benuni@DeShawn:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_connections
ls: cannot access /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf.d: No such file or directory
Listing connections ...
guest   127.0.0.1   64700   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64709   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64614   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64716   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64717   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64701   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64699   blocking
guest   127.0.0.1   64613   blocking
guest   127.0.0.1   64708   blocking
guest   127.0.0.1   64718   blocked
guest   127.0.0.1   64706   blocked
...done.
```

SO for some reason the rabbitmq server is blocking my connections?
Does anyone know what i need to do?
Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check log for messages like:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Jul-2012::13:38:02 ===
Disk free space limit now exceeded. Free bytes:13114646528 Limit:15740784640
```

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/16493 for more info

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about this post. That was the problem in the end. Should have updated it myself

Answer (score 1):

When you are seeing connections blocked like that, it means you're probably exceeding the watermark level of disk and/or memory.

See: http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html for more info.